# Execute Procedures in dataform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataform

I am trying to figure out a way to execute Procedures in Dataform.  Basically the requirement is to not execute scripts for table updates, if it has been updated on the same day already.
This is only possible using procedures by checking update time.  I cannot use incremental as record history based on dates has complications.

Comment: Hi @RaptorX execute procedures in dataform seems like a feature request.So If you want this feature in Dataform, you can raise a feature request in [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests).

Comment: Solved using pre and post operations, that is packaged in dataform, instead of trying to execute a procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Dataform supports invocation of Javascript functions with `Operations` config type. Within Dataform you can created the Javascript function in a file under `includes` folder.

In `JSFileName.js` add this

```
function ProcedureCaller(name, uris) {
    return `CALL project-id.my-dataset.my_procedure()`;
}
    
module.exports = {
    ProcedureCaller
};
```

Then create a `operations` config file that will invoke the Javascript function which inturn invokes the procedure.

```
config {
    type: "operations",
    tags: ["updates procedure"]
}
 
${JSFileName.ProcedureCaller()}
```